# how to symlink a style file into subdirectories?

Tags: packages, texlive, mactex

I have a project that comprises multiple sub-documents, each of which needs to be generated many times with small tweaks that need to be consistent across the document. Here's what I want to do:

1. create a style file in which I define some macros containing the information needing to be tweaked,
2. place each sub-document in its own subfolder,
3. symlink the single style file to each subfolder,

so that

4. I can just tweak the style file and rebuild each document rather than having to tweak each document individually hoping I don't forget something.

Here's what I tried.

- I create a directory `<minimal>`, with a subdirectory `<doc1>`.
- I create `mwe.sty` and put it in the home `<minimal>` directory:

`mwe,sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mwe}

\newcommand{\foo}{bar}
```

- I create `doc1.tex` in `minimal/doc1`:

`minimal/doc1/doc1.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}   
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\foo
\end{document}
```

- I symlink the style file into `doc1` with:

```
ln -s mwe.sty doc1/mwe.sty
```

- I `cd` into `doc1` try to build with:

compilation:

```
latex doc1.tex
```

and I get:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \foo
```

I'm on Mactex 2015. Anybody got an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Why don't you just drop the style file into your TEXMFHOME? Then you don't need the symbolic links at all. `mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/shane-mwe && mv mwe.sty $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/shane-mwe/snane-mwe.sty`. (Don't use `mwe.sty` because there's already a package by that name in the standard distributions.)

Comment: But if you do want to use symbolic links, try `cd minimal/doc1; ln -s ../shane-mwe.sty ./`. Or `ln -s ../shane-mwe.sty doc1/shane-mwe.sty`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't use the same name as that of a standard package. So let's use `shane-mwe.sty` rather than `mwe.sty`, which already exists.

```
\ProvidesPackage{shane-mwe}
```

```
cd minimal && mv mwe.sty shane-mwe.sty
```

To see what is wrong with the existing symbolic link, do

```
ls -l doc1/mwe.sty
```

and you will see that the link points to itself.

To create a link to the parent directory, you need something like

```
ln -s ../shane-mwe.sty doc1/shane-mwe.sty
```

or

```
cd doc1/ && ln -s ../shane-mwe.sty ./
```

However, it would probably be better and easier to drop the style file in your `TEXMFHOME` since that is what it is designed for.

```
mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/shane-mwe && mv shane-mwe.sty $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/shane-mwe/
```

Comment: yep, that does it. I didn't want to install anything to my TEXMFHOME because i've got the same project synced to a bunch of different machines via github and I didn't want to have to go crawling into tex's guts to make a couple of simple changes a whole lot of times. Many thanks!